# Android Save Drawing /

Tags: android, image, save, drawing2d

In the API Demos is a drawing example called FingerPaint.

```
package com.example.android.apis.graphics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class FingerPaint extends GraphicsActivity
        implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                                       0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);

            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static final int COLOR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int EMBOSS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int BLUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    private static final int ERASE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
    private static final int SRCATOP_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, COLOR_MENU_ID, 0, "Color").setShortcut('3', 'c');
        menu.add(0, EMBOSS_MENU_ID, 0, "Emboss").setShortcut('4', 's');
        menu.add(0, BLUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Blur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, ERASE_MENU_ID, 0, "Erase").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, SRCATOP_MENU_ID, 0, "SrcATop").setShortcut('5', 'z');

        /****   Is this the mechanism to extend with filter effects?
        Intent intent = new Intent(null, getIntent().getData());
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        menu.addIntentOptions(
                              Menu.ALTERNATIVE, 0,
                              new ComponentName(this, NotesList.class),
                              null, intent, 0, null);
        *****/
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case COLOR_MENU_ID:
                new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
                return true;
            case EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case BLUR_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case ERASE_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                        PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                return true;
            case SRCATOP_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
                mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I would like to save the drawing as an image such as a png file to the phone. I added this code:

```
    case SAVE_MENU_ID:
        String filename = "signature.png";
        getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()
                .setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap b = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()
                .getDrawingCache();

        OutputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/signature.png");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
         * Write bitmap to file using JPEG or PNG and 80% quality hint for
         * JPEG.
         */
        // bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The image, signature.png is getting saved to the phone, but it is 0 bytes in size. I had added to my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You should probably uncomment the line that actually SAVES the image.

Comment: Could u make sure that your `Bitmap b` is not empty? (I mean it should have some data inside, but not null)

Comment: @ ss1271, no Bitmap b was not empty

Comment: @ 323go Yes, I needed to uncomment that line. I had it commented out because it came from example code from another example, and the new example I was looking at did not use that line.

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be

```
     stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

              than

      stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/signature.png");  

      FileOutputStream(File file)
      Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to file.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html.

Also UnComment the below

```
      bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
```

You can use a alertdialog to allow user to give a name to the draw being saved.

Once user types the name and click's ok you can save the draw in your sdcard under that name.

In my code content is the rootview;

```
 case SAVE_MENU_ID:

                AlertDialog.Builder editalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(DrawingRoomScreen.this);
                editalert.setTitle("Please Enter the name with which you want to Save");
                final EditText input = new EditText(DrawingRoomScreen.this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                input.setLayoutParams(lp);
                editalert.setView(input);
                editalert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        String name= input.getText().toString();
                        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();

                     String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 
                        File file = new File("/sdcard/"+name+".png");           
                        try 
                        {
                            if(!file.exists())
                        {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
                            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
                            System.out.println("saving......................................................"+path);
                            ostream.close();
                            content.invalidate();                           
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally
                        {

                            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);                          
                        }
                    }
                });

                editalert.show();

   break;
```